# GoogleGenerativeAIError: [400 Bad Request] API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, google-gemini

I am following [this](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/node_quickstart) tutorial from Google on using Gemini in Node applications; I have followed all the steps, created an API key from Google AI Studio; encased it inside an env file, and called it in the app.js file to generate text as seen from this snippet of code

```
const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");

// Access your API key as an environment variable (see "Set up your API key" above)
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.API_KEY);

async function run() {
  // For text-only input, use the gemini-pro model
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-pro"});

  const prompt = "Write a story about a magic backpack."

  const result = await model.generateContent(prompt);
  const response = await result.response;
  const text = response.text();
  console.log(text);
}

run();
```

Unfortunately when I run `node app` in the terminal I get this error
[image: Error Message]instead of receiving a response; I have tried google searches and chat GPT and came up with nothing substantial or helpful.

Any pointers to resources that can help me solve this error are greatly appreciated and welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Are you using something like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to load environment variables from your `.env` file?

Comment: Hey @Phil I was using it without installing the dotenv package; so I just added dotenv this morning after speaking to a friend and he pointed it out for me;

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure your node version is >= 18.

Comment: My node version is 18.16.0

Answer (score -3):

I spoke to a friend and realized that the API key was right but it wasn't being parsed the right way in the app.js file

I had to run `npm install dotenv --save` to install the dotenv package and after which I added the line as seen in the code below

[image: Line of code added]

This solved the error and successfully gives me a response as seen below
[image: Response in the terminal]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.